# How to retrieve variable from component to another in Angular? (not in the Html page, but in the component)

Tags: angular, typescript, variables, input, components

In the child component, I have a string :

```
@Input() helloMessage:string;
```

I need this string to take the value from another string from the parent component and to access this value into the child component. I don't need the value to be visible in the html, and I don't know how to pass access the variable from the parent component.
So `this.helloMessage=parentComponentVariable`, because I need to use the helloMessage variable into the methods from the child component.

Answer (score 0):

This is a basic data binding concept. Try something similar to the following.
Child Component TS file

```
@Input() helloMessageChild:string;
```

Parent Component TS file

```
helloMessageParent = '';
```

Prent Component HTML file

```
<app-child-component [helloMessageChild]="helloMessageParent"></app-child-component>
```

https://angular.io/guide/two-way-binding

This is the standard way. If don't want data binding for any reason you have to use the service with BehaviorSubject. You have to emit data from the parent and subscribe the data emit in the child.

https://medium.com/@weswhite/angular-behaviorsubject-service-60485ef064fc

In practice, service is used to pass data from one component to another where there is no parent-child relationship.

Comment: But I don't need to link the connection in the html page, but in the component. In the child component i need to retrieve the value of the parent component variable.

Comment: If you trying to do something other than data binding or subscription to observable then you are doing it wrong in the angular world.